# Error downloading nuget package from nexus

Tags: nuget, nexus

I am trying to manage nuget package via internet Nexus repository.

We are using nexus 3.5.1-02 and it supports nuget packages.

I have already configured nuget.org as Proxy.

[image]

When I try to install nuget package, following error occurs.

[image]

What might cause this problem? Any idea?